# How can I find the lagging region on minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have minecraft server with a bunch of mods: [here the list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsJGELm4ir_edHNERWNGS1BZTEVaZUJ5XzhsMEprSEE&usp=sharing#gid=0). The thing is after I explored a big part of world my server began to lag **(before that server worked good)**. When I replaced world with old version of the same world (before exploration and with the same set of mods) lags disappeared. So, I think, I found something in the world that causes lags. How can I find that lagging region and remove the source of lag (kill problem mob, for example, regenerate region)?

This is what I get in console when server starts to lag:

```
16:24:11 [WARNING] The server is going slow. Last server tick was 20004ms ago
16:24:11 [WARNING] Last Tick: 1398345831441 Current Time: 1398345851445 Warning:
 20000 Timeout: 60000
16:24:11 [WARNING] [TPS]: 16.7 Server Tick #54000
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Dimension:0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Loaded Chunks: 336 Active Chunks: 154 Entities: 127 Tile Entities: 860
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Entities Last Tick: 83
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Tiles Last Tick: 660
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Dimension:7
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Loaded Chunks: 0 Active Chunks: 0 Entities: 0 Tile Entities: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Entities Last Tick: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Tiles Last Tick: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Dimension:-17
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Loaded Chunks: 0 Active Chunks: 0 Entities: 0 Tile Entities: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Entities Last Tick: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Tiles Last Tick: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Dimension:-31
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Loaded Chunks: 0 Active Chunks: 0 Entities: 0 Tile Entities: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Entities Last Tick: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Tiles Last Tick: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Dimension:-100
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Loaded Chunks: 0 Active Chunks: 0 Entities: 0 Tile Entities: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Entities Last Tick: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Tiles Last Tick: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Dimension:1
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Loaded Chunks: 0 Active Chunks: 0 Entities: 0 Tile Entities: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Entities Last Tick: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Tiles Last Tick: 0
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Dimension:-1
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Loaded Chunks: 26 Active Chunks: 9 Entities: 42 Tile Entities: 19
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Entities Last Tick: 3
16:24:11 [WARNING]   Tiles Last Tick: 8
```

**Minecraft v1.6.4

mcpc+ (forge + bukkit)

Essentials core plugin installed**

Comment: @MBraedley, I didn't find solution there, my lags, as I discovered after trying what was in answers to that questions, have nothing to do with redstone.

Comment: It seems like using Opis is your solution.  Have you tried it yet?  Sure, it's not one of the top voted answers, but that's probably because it's a mod instead of an external editor or vanilla solution.